# Вопросительная интонация с "представляешь"

Tags: пунктуация, разговорная-речь, интонация

Нередко в разговорной речи употребляют это *"представляешь"* (или *"представляете"*) в начале фразы, и произносится оно с вопросительной интонацией. Например:

> *Представляешь, у меня телефон так и не сломался! Заработал опять.*

*Правильно ли я понимаю, что, несмотря на эту вопросительную интонацию, вопросительный знак в конце **никогда** не надо ставить, потому что по сути это не вопрос, а средство привлечения внимания собеседника, чем-то даже схожее с междометием?*

Comment: Не могу понять, где вы услышали вопросительную интонацию... хотя интонацию каждый слышит, как хочет. Конечно, вопросительный знак в подобных предложениях неуместен.

Comment: Спасибо, что подтвердили мою уверенность насчёт знака. Вопросительную интонацию совершенно чётко слышу! На -ля- она поднимается выше всего, к -ешь немного опускается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово ***представляешь*** является вводным, это **обращение к собеседнику** с целью привлечь его внимание к сообщаемому, внушить определенное отношение к излагаемым мыслям, приводимым фактам.

Сравним, к примеру, слова ***представляете*** и ***представьте***. Первое слово действительно можно считать вопросом, но произносим мы его с разной интонацией, вернее, с **разными интонационными оттенками**   в зависимости от того, какими чувствами хотим поделиться.

Слово ***представляешь*** можно произнести с обычной (ровной) интонацией, без эмоций, тогда оно равносильно сочетанию ***обратите внимание***. Можно использовать вопросительную интонацию, если хотим выразить **удивление** (разве такое бывает?). Иногда же нам надо поделиться своей **радостью**, тогда это восклицательная интонация.

**Вопросительная** интонация связана с повышением тона на ударном слоге, а **восклицательная** устроена немного сложнее: тон сначала повышается, при этом делается силовое ударение, но потом  идет понижение тона. Также меняется тембр голоса, выражая различные эмоции (положительные или отрицательные).

Поэтому вопросительное по своей природе  слово мы произносим по-разному, и это его характерная особенность по сравнению с другими вводными словами этой группы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Так "?" никогда не надо ставить, даже при вопросительной интонации?

Comment: Для этого вводное слово надо сделать отдельным предложением: Представляешь? Ты представляешь? Пример: Он спросил ― "Войнович?" Он меня узнал! Ты представляешь?!. Писателям, уезжающим в Америку, есть смысл задуматься: [Сергей Довлатов. Переводные картинки // «Иностранная литература», 1990]

Comment: Ясно, спасибо!)